# Can some explain this PL/SQL statement to me in detail?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

```
DECLARE
    p NUMBER := 0;
    q NUMBER := 1;
    r NUMBER;
BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LPAD('0: ', 4) || LPAD(p, 10)); 
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LPAD('1: ', 4) || LPAD(q, 10)); 
    FOR k IN 2..20 LOOP 
        r := p + q;
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LPAD(k, 2) || ': ' || LPAD(r, 10)); 
            p := q;
            q := r;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

We went over this in one of my classes but I didnt really get a good understanding to how this for loop works.  I know the output prints numbers 0-20 on the left and I am confused at how the numbers on the right increase as they do.

Comment: which part made you confused dude? or the whole code went above the head? be specific in `SO`.

Comment: Ok, I now get that the Fibonacci numbers are the sum of the two previous numbers before the next number.  How could someone display Fn-3, Fn, and Fn+3 ? Does this mean it increments by 3 every time?

Answer (score 1):

the sequence printed are the [fibonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number). their recursive definition reads: `a_n = a_(n-1) + a_(n-2)`. in the code snippet, `p` takes the role of `a_(n-2)`, `q` that of `a_(n-1)`. imagine the sequence printed out from the right to the left with a sliding window (`r, q, p`) superimposed. in each iteration, the window moves one step to the left. the `lpad` function pads a string to the given length. you may optionally add a 3rd argument, the padding character (defaults to ). notet that there is a sibling function `rpad`. but you probably know this if the code has been discussed in class.

Comment: How could I get this loop to begin at 30 and end at 80 and not display the number not in that range?

Comment: @DaBulls33 I have given the solution

Answer (score 0):

@DaBulls33 Please find your required solution below

```
DECLARE
p NUMBER := 0;
q NUMBER := 1;
r NUMBER;
BEGIN
FOR k IN 2..80 LOOP 
    r := p + q;
     IF K >29 THEN
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(LPAD(k, 2) || ': ' || LPAD(r, 10));
      END IF;
        p := q;
        q := r;
END LOOP;
END;
```